# Let $G$ be subgroup of $GL_n(F)$, $SL_n(F)\subset G$, where $F$ is a field. Prove that $G$ is normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be subgroup of $GL_n(F)$, $SL_n(F)\subset G$, where $F$ is a field. Prove that $G$ is normal subgroup.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your thoughts and attempts about the problem in your post.

Comment: What is the structure of $GL_n(F)/SL_n(F)$?

Comment: @Xam I wish I had any thought about the problem. It would be great if someone gave a hint.

Comment: @Lord $F^*$ -- multiplicative group of field $F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g\in G$, and any $x\in GL_n(F)$. We want to show that $xgx^{-1}$ lies in $G$. It's enough to show that $g^{-1}xgx^{-1}$ lies in $G$. (Why?) But, the latter one has determinant $1$ (since determinant is multiplicative and $F$ is commutative), so it lies in $G$ by your assumption of $SL_n(F)$.